File Upload in GraalVM native build in Swagger API V3 showing text input instead of file upload
While I was developing a new reactive endpoint in Spring boot V3 as follows:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/stats")
public class StatsController {

  @PostMapping(
    consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE
  )
  @ResponseStatus(OK)
  public Flux<String> index(@RequestPart("file") Flux<FilePart> file) {

  }
}

Then I have the following configuration for the SwaggerV3 as follows:
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi storeOpenApi() {
        String[] paths = { "/stats/**" };

        return GroupedOpenApi
            .builder()
            .group("Dummy Description")
            .pathsToMatch(paths)
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public OpenApiCustomizer customiseOpenApi() {
        return openApi -> openApi.getPaths()
            .forEach((path, pathItem) -> pathItem.readOperations().forEach(operation -> {
                if (path.equals("/stats") && operation.getOperationId() != null && operation.getOperationId().equals("index")) {
                    RequestBody requestBody = new RequestBody()
                        .required(true)
                        .content(new Content().addMediaType("multipart/form-data",
                            new io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.MediaType().schema(new Schema<>()
                                .type("object")
                                .addProperty("file", new Schema<>().type("string").format("binary"))
                            )
                        ));
                    operation.setRequestBody(requestBody);
                }
            }));
    }
}

And in my pom.xml I have the dependencies list as follows:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>

The good thing is that it shows file upload input normally on normal spring boot run using the command: ./mvnw spring-boot:run on a normal local JVM v21
But the issue comes when I build a GraalVM and run the application and check the same input and find it as text instead of file upload.
How can we fix this issue?
Please be noted that it is reactive springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui and GraalVM

After some hours of search and destroy tactical operations,
I found it  spotted
I had to place a file called
srs/main/resources/META-INF/native-image/reflect-config.json
with these contents:

[
  {
    "name": "org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.FilePart",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredFields": true
  },
  {
    "name": "org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.FilePart[]",
    "unsafeAllocated": true
  }
]


And hooray, it finally worked
